# Setting the width of the Material drawer same as child in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, navigation-drawer

I am trying to modify the width material drawer example provided in their official document https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#permanent-drawer.

How can I set Material Drawer width to the width of its children in Reactjs? As I only wish the navbar to show material icon only but not the text.

Currently, the example uses a constant value to define the width of the drawer. I would like to remove that

```
const drawerWidth = 200;
      <Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: "border-box",
          },
        }}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
      >
```

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import MuiAppBar, { AppBarProps as MuiAppBarProps } from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Mail";

const drawerWidth = 60;

const Main = styled("main", { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open" })<{
  open?: boolean;
}>(({ theme, open }) => ({
  flexGrow: 1,
  padding: theme.spacing(3),
  transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  marginLeft: `-${drawerWidth}px`,
  ...(open && {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
  }),
}));

interface AppBarProps extends MuiAppBarProps {
  open?: boolean;
}

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open",
})<AppBarProps>(({ theme, open }) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const DrawerHeader = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  justifyContent: "flex-end",
}));

export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{ mr: 2, ...(open && { display: "none" }) }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            Persistent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: "border-box",
          },
        }}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
      >
        <DrawerHeader>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
      </Drawer>
      <Main open={open}>
        <DrawerHeader />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus
          dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Risus at
          ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum
          quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit
          laoreet id donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed
          adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies
          integer quis. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Metus vulputate
          eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo. Mauris commodo
          quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat
          vivamus at augue. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur
          lorem. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem donec massa sapien
          faucibus et molestie ac.
        </Typography>
      </Main>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I tried to remove the `const drawerWidth = 200;` but the whole drawer thing is broken. I am new to Mui, any help is appreciated.